# Moving pagecontrol inside container

Tags: swift, containers, uipagecontrol, pagecontrol

I currently have a main viewcontroller that has a container in it.  This container holds a pageviewcontroller with 3 different view controllers that it uses.  Each one has its own colour.  Green blue and pink.  Everything is functional however I want the dots to appear inside the coloured frame instead of outside it.  How can I change the position of my pagecontrols?

```
  import Foundation
  import UIKit
   class TestPageController: UIPageViewController{

private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.newColoredViewController(color: "Green"),
            self.newColoredViewController(color: "Blue"),
            self.newColoredViewController(color: "Pink")]
}()

private func newColoredViewController(color: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
        instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(color)ViewController")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dataSource = self
    configPageControl()
    if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
        setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                           direction: .forward,
                           animated: true,
                           completion: nil)
    }
}
func configPageControl(){
 var pageController = UIPageControl.appearance()
    pageController.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear()
    pageController.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black()
    pageController.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blue()
 }

  }




extension TestPageController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource{


    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return orderedViewControllers.count
    }
    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return nil
        }

        guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count

        guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use a UIPageControl (and place on the position that you want and set the numberOfPages property), then using the delegate methods of `UIPageControllerDelegate`:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if finished && completed{
        if let actualController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first as? MyViewController{
            self.pageControl.currentPage = actualController.index
        }
    }
}
```